# New instance in switch

Tags: java, design-patterns, instantiation

I'm currently learning java and oop.
I'm having a problem when I have to instantiate a new object depending on a condition. Each object has the same type.
Depending on the condition, I would like to pass my object playerAnimal and animalSauvage in order to let them fight. (it's kind of a player meeting a savage Pokemon).

```
switch (animalChosen) {
    case "Chien":
        Animaux playerChien = new Chien(animalName);
        playerChien.displayStat();
        break;
    case "Chat":
        Animaux playerChat = new Chat(animalName);
        playerChat.displayStat();
        break;
    case "Furet":
        Animaux playerFuret = new Furet(animalName);
        playerFuret.displayStat();
        break;
    default
        break;
}

switch (randAnimalSauvage()) {
    case "Chien":
        Animaux chienSauvage = new Chien();
        chienSauvage.displayStat();
        break;
    case "Chat":
        Animaux chatSauvage = new Chat();
        chatSauvage.displayStat();
        break;
    case "Furet":
        Animaux furetSauvage = new Furet();
        furetSauvage.displayStat();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
Fight letsFight = new Fight(Animaux playerAnimal, Animaux animalSauvage);
letsFight.battle(Animaux playerAnimal, Animaux animalSauvage);
```

PS: I'm french, don't mind the meaning of the variable name ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: You can use the same variable name, `player` & `chat` maybe, initialize it an then use it for the Flight object creation.

Comment: When you call a method or a constructor, don't pass the types of the parameters, only the values, i.e `new Fight(playerAnimal, animalSauvage)` and `letsFight.battle(playerAnimal, animalSauvage);` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
Animal animal= null;
switch (animalChosen) {
    case "Chien":
        animal = new Chien(animalName);
        break;
    case "Chat":
        animal = new Chat(animalName);
        break;
    case "Furet":
        animal = new Furet(animalName);
        break;
      default
        break;
 }
 animal.displayStat();
```

This works because (I assume, and that's what needs to be the case) that all of `Chien`, `Chat` and `Furet` are subclasses of `Animal` (or implement the interface, whatever it is).

It's the same for the enemy Animal. Since it's the same for both cases, you can just create a function.

```
private Animal byName(String animalName) {
    // same code as above, returning the animal
    return animal;
}
```

which would then be called like this:

```
Animal playerAnimal = byName(playerChoice);
Animal savageAnimal = byName(randAnimalSauvage());
Fight letsFight = new Fight(playerAnimal, savageAnimal);
letsFight.battle(playerAnimal, savageAnimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Animaux chosenPlayerAnimal;

    switch (animalChosen) {
        case "Chien":
            chosenPlayerAnimal = new Chien(animalName);
            break;
        case "Chat":
            chosenPlayerAnimal = new Chat(animalName);
            break;
        case "Furet":
            chosenPlayerAnimal = new Furet(animalName);
            break;
        default:
            chosenPlayerAnimal = new SomeDefaultAnimal(animalName);
            break;
    }

    Animaux animalSauvage;

    switch (randAnimalSauvage()) {
        case "Chien":
            animalSauvage = new Chien();
            break;
        case "Chat":
            animalSauvage = new Chat();
            break;
        case "Furet":
            animalSauvage = new Furet();
            break;
        default:
            animalSauvage = SomeDefaultAnimal();
            break;
    }

    chosenPlayerAnimal.displayStat();
    animalSauvage.displayStat();

    Fight letsFight = new Fight(chosenPlayerAnimal, animalSauvage);
    letsFight.battle(chosenPlayerAnimal, animalSauvage);
```

I don't really get why you're calling `Fight.battle()` with the animals you already provided in the constructor.

Comment: thanks a lot! my method is kinda big so I would like to create a class especially for the battle. :)